# Docusign change recipient for notification events

Tags: notifications, docusignapi

If this has already been posted, I apologize, I couldn't find an answer.
I am using the c# API.
We would like to specify, on a document by document base, who will receive the notification events.

As a for example:
We have our business segmented into regions.
Documents signed in any given region should send their notifications to the regional rep.  Currently, all notifications go to one person, and they have to forward the notifications.  It would be nice if I could set this up when I create the envelope, so the notification events go to the regional rep right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever is the sender of an envelope will receive the notifications, you cannot explicitly tell DocuSign to whom to send the notifications. If you want PersonA of RegionA to get notification then you need to send envelope on behalf of PersonA, then that user will become the owner of the envelope. Also it depends which type of notifications you are interested in, if you want to have notification like, Completed, Void, Expired then you can add your Regional Rep as CC recipient type as 1st in routing order then if any activity will happen on that envelope then CC recipient will get Completed, Void, Expired types of notification. The notification they will not get is, if someone has viewed an envelope.

Comment: We have our business principal email as the primary owner of the docusign account. 
 I want to keep the business principal email as the email in Docusign, to receive billing, Docusign correspondence, etc.  But we send contracts to multiple recipients.  And if they void, approve, expire, etc, we really want that notice to go to the sales rep, not the business principal email.

Comment: So you said 'send on behalf of'.  So I started looking into that term.  We have subscribed to the basic plan.  The basic plan only allows for one email, unless I am missing something.  It appears we would need to upgrade to add more than 1 email account, is that correct?

Once we upgrade, then it appears that I can do an API call to send on behalf of one of the other users on the account, is that correct?

If my assumptions are correct, then I think you have answered my question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you need to have more uses in your account, because you will be able to call on other user's behalf only, if those users are present in your DS Account. And the recommended way is  [OAUTH way] (https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html), here you need to capture the Access Token of the user for whom you are planning to send an envelope, and once envelope is sent then that user will get the proper notifications.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I greatly appreciate it.